# Simplifying the "cat's eye" function $f(z) = \frac {(e^x + 1)z + (e^x - 1)} {(e^x - 1)z + (e^x + 1)}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, hyperbolic-geometry, mobius-transformation

So I'm trying to find a solution of this function for $z = e^{i\theta}$ and for $x \in \Re$ and $\theta \in \Re$

> $$f(z) = \frac {(e^x + 1)z + (e^x - 1)} {(e^x - 1)z + (e^x + 1)}$$

First of all, does this function has a name?

I have the feeling that the result should be on the unit circle but I'm not able to find a satisfying solution by myself.

I've found that when $z \in \Re$ then $f(z) \in \Re$
Also, $f(1) = 1$ and $f(-1) = -1$ and if $x=0$ then $f(z)=z$

I tried to replace $e^{i\theta}$ by $cos(\theta) + i*sin(\theta)$ with no success. Here's what I got :

$f(e^{i\theta}) = \frac {e^{2x} + 1 + cos(\theta)*(e^x + 1)} {(e^x - 1)^2 + cos(\theta)*(e^x - 1)} + i*\frac{2e^x*sin(\theta)} {(e^x - 1)^2 + cos(\theta)*(e^x - 1)}$

Is there a way to simplify the writing of the function when $z=e^{i\theta}$ ? Is there a way to know if the solution lie on the unit circle?

Comment: What do you mean by 'solving' the equation? Do you mean solving $f(z)=0$?

Comment: @IanMiller I want to find the general form of the solutions. Specifically I want to know if points on the unit disk stay on the unit disk.

Comment: @IanMiller It seems like for $\theta = π/2$ and $x=1$ it is not even inside the unit disk which surprises me

Comment: Sorry I didn't look at the tags. I am unfamiliar with mobius-transformations so assume the language makes sense to someone knowledgable.

Comment: @IanMiller The fault is mine. I realised that talking about equation wasn't correct. I edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a fact proven in complex analysis that the Moebius transforms of the form
$$S(z):=e^{i\alpha}{z-c\over 1-\bar c z},\qquad \alpha\in{\mathbb R},\quad |c|<1,$$
map the unit disc conformally onto itself, whereby the (complex) point $c$ is mapped to the origin. By continuity such an $S$ will map the unit circle $\partial D$ bijectively onto itself.

In the case at hand we have $\alpha =0$ and $c={1-e^t\over 1+e^t}=-\tanh{t\over2}$:
$$f(z):={(e^t+1)z+(e^t-1)\over(e^t-1)z+(e^t+1)}={z-c\over 1-\bar c z}\ .$$
It follows that points $z:=e^{i\theta}$ are mapped to $\partial D$ by the given $f$.

Comment: It seems to be exactly what I was looking for. Unfortunatly I am not able to go from one writing to the other one. I think there's some simplification I'm missing somewhere when I develop the $\frac {z-c}{1-cz}$ Anyway, $f(i) = i$ with your function which seems more apropriate. Many thanks

Comment: OK. I managed to simplify it on my own. That was easier than expected.